# Javascript wrong/different date time is extracted from the UTC converted date

Tags: javascript, angular, timezone, utc

I have a date in local format , I changed it to UTC format . After UTC i want to extract date and time in UTC . But whenever I am trying to extract time or date for that matter , it is considering local time only , why is that ?

```
          this.utcDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.onceDate,'medium');
          console.log('+=timezonenene=+', this.utcDate);

          this.utcDateStr = new Date(this.utcDate).toUTCString();
          console.log('++ date is ++', this.utcDateStr);

          this.utcDateStr = new Date(this.utcDateStr).toISOString();
          console.log('++ date is ++', this.utcDateStr);

          this.showDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.utcDateStr, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
          this.showTime = this.datePipe.transform(this.utcDateStr, 'HH:mm');
          console.log('+=time date zonenene date str =+', this.showDate);
          console.log('+=timezonenene date str=+', this.showTime);
```

output :

```
+=timezonenene=+ Apr 7, 2020, 5:41:16 PM
++ date is ++ Tue, 07 Apr 2020 12:11:16 GMT
++ date is ++ 2020-04-07T12:11:16.000Z
+=time date zonenene date str =+ 2020-04-07
+=timezonenene date str=+ 17:41
```

I want last logged time as : 12:11 not 17:41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to be about the [Angular DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) (though you're calling the `transform` function directly).

From the docs about the `timezone` parameter:

> When not supplied, uses the end-user's local system timezone.

Thus, to get UTC output, you can change your code to provide the time zone parameter `'UTC'` after the format parameter, on each call to `datePipe.transform`.

Also, I'd reconsider why you are producing strings just to parse them again.  Usually this is unnecessary, and can lead to errors.  if `this.onceDate` is a `Date` object, you should be able to use that throughout your code, rather than creating `this.utcDateStr` just to parse and transform it again.  (Though it's difficult to tell from your code if that is the case.  In the future, please supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

Comment: certainly , yea , if we can get the utc time directly , no need of converting it to utc string , thanks .